# can't connect my android app to the net, only through my home wifi it work fine

Tags: android, network-programming, android-wifi

I am building an app in Android Studio, and using a sql server, the app works great on my home WIFI network. I manage to connect to the server and do enter / read / update the data.

But the **problem** is that outside the home network the app does not work, why?

(its work fine in the home wifi, but when i'm going out of range of my wifi, its not working\connecting)

The SQL SERVER is on my home computer (meaning the same IP)

**how to make it work on any android phone app and Everywhere ?**

````
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionClass {
   
    String ip = "192.168.1.15"; 
    String classes = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "myDB";
    String un = "mtun";
    String password = "mypw";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL;
        try {
            Class.forName(classes);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"+db+";user=" + un+ ";password=" + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERROR-1", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR-2", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR-3", e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;
    }
}```
````

Comment: you should host your local server 192.168.1.15 to somewhere where everybody can access it.

Comment: if I understand correctly, it's only connected when you are using your home WIFI? that's because you seem to be connecting to your local wifi which is located at 192.168.1.15

Comment: @AlphaOne how can i host my local server 192.168.1.15 to somewhere ?

Comment: @DanielAlome how can i make everybody to connect my app\server ?

Comment: @GalPic You need to purchase and configure a server to host your SQL Server Database, after that you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: @AlphaOne thank you so mutch

Comment: No you should not host any development server where *anybody* could access it. Comment should have been reported.